# Routes helpers dont work on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm upgrading a Rails 3 app to 3.1 and some reason the url helpers don't work in views.

e.g.: If I try to get to `reports_path` it can't be resolved, and i'm getting the `The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]` error, but if I use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.reports_path`, everything works smoothly?

Any ideas?

Comment: Run rake routes in your terminal and see what you get

Comment: when running `rake routes` I do see all the routes

Comment: Can you share more detail? What's your view look like?

Comment: something very simple: `<%= reports_path%>`